Oracle SQL - efficient use of the LAST_VALUE and OVER functions
I have two Oracle SQL tables which can be updated independently of each other but the sum of the versions provides a unique version required for other joins. The issue is that the linking column only updates in the joined table when it is updated. Therefore, when summing the version numbers there are gaps or duplicates. I need to have a definitive way to calculate this unique version which can be run efficiently in bulk as the version and ID are used to join many other tables. The below is one example but the code needs to be robust enough to cater for any scenarios. Note that table 1 must exist for table 2 to exist. On the other hand, Table 2 may not have a corresponding ID or version so can be null.
Table1:
Insert into TABLE1 (ID,TABLE1_VER,AUDIT_DATETIME) values ('0002073263',1,to_date('10/30/2023 09:57:05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

Insert into TABLE1 (ID,TABLE1_VER,AUDIT_DATETIME) values ('0002073263',2,to_date('10/30/2023 09:57:06','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

Insert into TABLE1 (ID,TABLE1_VER,AUDIT_DATETIME) values ('0002073263',3,to_date('10/30/2023 09:57:34','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

table1 :

Table2:
Insert into TABLE2 (ID,TABLE2_VER,AUDIT_DATETIME,ASSOCIATED_VERSION_TABLE1) values ('0002073263',1,to_date('10/30/2023 09:57:05','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),1);

Insert into TABLE2 (ID,TABLE2_VER,AUDIT_DATETIME,ASSOCIATED_VERSION_TABLE1) values ('0002073263',2,to_date('10/30/2023 10:55:04','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),3);

Insert into TABLE2 (ID,TABLE2_VER,AUDIT_DATETIME,ASSOCIATED_VERSION_TABLE1) values ('0002073263',3,to_date('10/30/2023 10:55:22','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),3);

table2 :

When I join these together using a full outer join on table1.ID = table2.ID AND table1.TRADE1_VER = table2.ASSOCIATED_VERSION_TABLE1 I get issues with the join as not all versions are associated and imply a previous version needs to be found:
joined data :

The correct output for this example should be the following which is found when looking at the timestamps for both tables. Table 1 advances versions quicker than table 2 but the associated version is only updated for the corresponding table1 version present at the time. Therefore, any interim versions are not linked to anything. This can be seen in table2 as there is no link to table1_VER=2 even though table2_VER = 1 was present at the time and should provide a COMBINED_VER of 3.
correct value :

This query needs to be run in bulk so needs to be efficient and avoid creating temporary tables. I need to use this 'KEY' (ID+"_"+version) to link onto other tables.

It is not clear how you wish to associate rows in table1 to table2. Why should ver 3 in table1 match all three rows in table2? If this is a real table and not an academic exercise, I would suggest seriously redesigning it so you don't have such a complicated set of interdependencies that can only cause problems.

Hi Paul, the date time is key here. TABLE1_VER 1 is created at 9.57.05. At the same time, TABLE2_VER1 is created giving 1+1 = 2. After this TABLE1 has 2 more versions created before table2 then has 2 more versions created. Therefore, you get the values shown in the final table. The table is in a legacy system which is looking to be migrated in the next few years so spending time and money amending it now is unlikely to get approval.

You haven't explained how table1_ver3 matches all three rows in table2. 9.57.34 is greater than 9.57.05 (table2_ver1) but less than 10.55.04/10.55.22 (table2 vers 2 and 3). So what's the logic that relates table1_ver3 to all three of table2's rows?

table1_ver3 matches all 3 rows because at 9.57.34 table 2 only has 1 version. When versions 2 and 3 of table2 are created, table 1 is already at version 3. so you get pairs as in the final table.

I'm afraid I don't understand your logic. If you could express it programmatically that would help communicate your need.

OVER windows are generally meaningless without an ORDER BY expression. In most cases, you can invert this expression and use FIRST_VALUE instead of LAST_VALUE to get the same result. Doing this will tend to be more efficient, because LAST_VALUE requires the database to walk the entire window set before it can know which value is the last one. Therefore, the efficient use of LAST_VALUE is not using it at all, and instead using FIRST_VALUE with the inverse ordering. In fact, the only time I've used LAST_VALUE is when I referenced a named window multiple times

On a side note: It is a bad idea to call a column ID, when it does not uniquely identify a row in the table. This is misleading and can confuse the people who have to work with the query. better call it group_key or the like for instance.

It seems that now you have three answers that all take your given input and produce your desired output. The only issue is that all three of these answers use different logic. I think it would be of benefit if you included any edges cases you know about in your input/output.

Not sure if this meets your criteria for 'efficient'...
Using the table versions in each respective table, we can do a self join to align the next records audit datetime. When there is no next audit datetime, we use a ridiculously large date. Doing this for both tables gives us an 'effective' timeframe for each row, which we can use to join these results together. The join is on a matching ID and the intersection/overlap of the timeframes. You could use a LEAD windowed function (instead of the self joins) to achieve the same result (and might be worth testing for performance comparison).
I define the timeframes (time1, time2) and (time3, time4) to be intersecting/overlapping if either time1 is between time3 and time4 OR time3 is between time1 and time2. I have used a completely inclusive intersection (i.e. a BETWEEN is inclusive on both ends), but you will likely want to resort to greater than/less than and have equality on only one end. This is for you to decide, and will depend on how you want to handle the edges cases of equivalent dates.
SELECT t1.TABLE1_VER
        , t2.TABLE2_VER
        , t1.TABLE1_VER + t2.TABLE2_VER AS COMBINED_VER
FROM (
    SELECT t1a.ID
        , t1a.TABLE1_VER
        , t1a.AUDIT_DATETIME
        , COALESCE(t1b.AUDIT_DATETIME, to_date('12/31/2999 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS NEXT_AUDIT_DATETIME
    FROM TABLE1 t1a
    LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1b
        ON t1a.ID = t1b.ID
            AND t1a.TABLE1_VER + 1 = t1b.TABLE1_VER
    )t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t2a.ID
        , t2a.TABLE2_VER
        , t2a.ASSOCIATED_VERSION_TABLE1
        , t2a.AUDIT_DATETIME
        , COALESCE(t2b.AUDIT_DATETIME, to_date('12/31/2999 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS NEXT_AUDIT_DATETIME
    FROM TABLE2 t2a
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2b
        ON t2a.ID = t2b.ID
            AND t2a.TABLE2_VER + 1 = t2b.TABLE2_VER
    ) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        AND (
        (t1.AUDIT_DATETIME BETWEEN t2.AUDIT_DATETIME AND t2.NEXT_AUDIT_DATETIME)
        OR
        (t2.AUDIT_DATETIME BETWEEN t1.AUDIT_DATETIME AND t1.NEXT_AUDIT_DATETIME)
        );

I've just done an inner join here, which gives your desired result. If you have a situation where there are IDs in one table not in the other (and vice-versa) you will need to do full join. In this scenario you will have to take extra care to deal with nulls on both sides.
try it yourself: db<>fiddle (this fiddle is cursed, I couldn't get the inserts to all run together had to separate them?).

It seems you want

for each table1 row the latest table2 row with the same ID and a datetime less or equal

and

for each table2 row the latest table1 row with the same ID and a datetime less or equal

For this you can use CROSS APPLY with FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY.
Union the two results to get your final result set:
select
  t1.table1_ver,
  t1.audit_datetime as t1_adt,
  t2.table2_ver,
  t2.audit_datetime as t2_adt,
  t1.table1_ver + t2.table2_ver as combined_ver
from table1 t1
cross apply 
(
  select *
  from table2 t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id
  and t2.audit_datetime <= t1.audit_datetime
  order by t2.audit_datetime desc
  fetch first row only
) t2
union
select
  t1.table1_ver,
  t1.audit_datetime as t1_adt,
  t2.table2_ver,
  t2.audit_datetime as t2_adt,
  t1.table1_ver + t2.table2_ver as combined_ver
from table2 t2
cross apply 
(
  select *
  from table1 t1 
  where t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.audit_datetime <= t2.audit_datetime
  order by t1.audit_datetime desc
  fetch first row only
) t1
order by combined_ver, table1_ver, table2_ver;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/kV4sDJjN
Indexes that may speed this up:
create index idx1 on table1 (id, audit_datetime);
create index idx2 on table2 (id, audit_datetime); 


Try this on your dataset, don't use DISTINCT, UNION or CROSS APPLY so could be more efficient if covering all your use cases:
select id, table1_ver, table2_ver, table1_ver + table2_ver as combined_ver
from (
    select t1.id, t1.table1_ver , t1.audit_datetime as t1_audit_datetime,
        t2.table2_ver, t2.audit_datetime as t2_audit_datetime
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.table1_ver = t2.associated_version_table1

    union all

    select t1.id, t1.table1_ver, t1.audit_datetime as t1_audit_datetime,
        t2.table2_ver, t2.audit_datetime as t2_audit_datetime
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.table1_ver <> t2.associated_version_table1
        and t1.audit_datetime >= t2.audit_datetime
)
order by id, table1_ver, table2_ver

At least give the expected result for your example data:



id
table1_ver
table2_ver
combined_ver




0002073263
1
1
2


0002073263
2
1
3


0002073263
3
1
4


0002073263
3
2
5


0002073263
3
3
6



